# Webpack doesn't catch the changes in Typescript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on an Angular project and use Webpack bundler. Everything was working fine until Webpack started to ignore my changes to Typescript files. When I change a Typescript file, Webpack first says:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
```

followed by:

```
[WDS] Nothing changed.
```

Also, killing webpack-dev-server and rebuilding the sources doesn't make any difference. The changes I make to TS files are not applied in any way.

**EDIT: Loader setup on request (which is exactly the same as in the Angular Developer Guide):**

webpack.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post more context? Like what is your loader setup, which version of Webpack are you using, etc.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks! Please see my edit.

Comment: @robertklep Does it cache the bundled files anywhere? Because it's strange that still my older code runs when I do an "npm start" and bundle the source again.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/99) shows the same problem, but it was solved some time ago already. I assume that you're using a relatively recent version of `awesome-typescript-loader`?

Comment: @robertklep I see in my package.json that I'm using v2.2.4.

Comment: I don't use TS myself so I can't help you there I'm afraid. I assume that with _"...my changes to JS files..."_, you mean TS files?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I meant TS files.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect the fact that you meant TypeScript files instead of JavaScript.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit just to be sure: the files you're changing are (eventually) imported by one of the `entry` files?

Comment: @robertklep Yes. app entry includes main.ts which in turn includes my component and services files, etc. The strange thing is, a previous version of my code runs every time, ignoring every change after that. I changed some of the console.log calls just to be sure and I can see the older debug messages printed to the console.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit did you change filenames at some point? Have you tried removing everything in `output.path` (`dist/`)?

Comment: In general you shouldn't use optimization plugins like `CommonChunksPlugin` and `ExtractTextPlugin` for local development. These complicate things. You should just let the dev server work it's convoluted magic on all your files and point to the one dev server `bundle.js`

Comment: @robertklep I couldn't find where the dist folder is so I deleted all the node_modules folder but to no avail.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit it's the result of `helpers.root('dist')`, that's where (for a standalone build) the bundled files will be written to.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I saw it but when I search for a folder named "dist" nothing comes up other than some folders under node_modules.

Comment: The problem boils down to the Typescript loader I guess. I manually compiled all the TS files and the Javascript files are up to date now. For some reason some of the TS files are not transpiled.